Magento 2 ups is not working with REST SERVICE option
I am using the UPS shipping method and I am getting shipping rates with the below option.

United Parcel Service XML

But as I change it to

United Parcel Service REST


then it stopped working and sending the below response.
Response:
{
"response":{
"errors":[
{
"code":"250002",
"message":"Invalid Authentication Information."
}
]
}
}


Possibly new credentials needs to be obtained on the UPS Developer page under My Apps.
Also under the available products Rating (and maybe more?) needs to be activated.
